# How to implement a RegEx library in C

Tags: c, finite-state-machine, regular-expressions

### Background

I have been attempting to create a line editor in C, eventually becoming a visual editor, and as a means of both allowing the editor to be useful but also learn more about C development, I would like to implement regex in the project, however, using a library I know (like C's regex library) would not satisfy the pedagogical/educational component of my goals.

### What I've done and other posts I've found

I have been searching for a while for some help on the matter (including but not limited to SO, Programmers SE and google scholar) and the closest I've gotten to my objectives was indeed a [magnificent article by Ken Thompson himself](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/363347.363387), however, of course, the level of detail he goes into and the language used (ALGOL-60) is not exactly friendly.

### Conclusion

Of course, I could just read the article again and again, however, I would also intend for a more, modern/practical point of view on how to develop/start developing such a library.

Any help would be appreciated (do mention if any additional information/refactoring is required).

Comment: The "modern and practical point of view on how to develop/start developing such a library" really is: "don't." Regular expression engines are hard, even in high level languages, and get vastly more complicated once you start having to worry about making them fast, safe (e.g. protecting against [ReDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS))). Doing the memory management of graph data structures in C is also pretty tricky. I would suggest flexing on some of your goals, if that at all possible. E.g. try implementing it in a higher level language, or a simplified subset of regex, etc.

Comment: Using search keywords "regex algorithm", one of the first links found by Google was this one: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Comment: One of the most modern and most well-designed regex implementations I have seen, is the [Rust `regex` crate](https://docs.rs/regex) ([Source code on GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex)). It guarantees linear search time (no [ReDOS](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS)) and is [fully safe for untrusted input and untrusted regexes](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/index.html#untrusted-input), has [extensive Unicode support](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/#unicode) (but [optional](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/#opt-out-of-unicode-support)), and lots of performance optimizations …

Comment: … ([which can be disabled](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/index.html#performance-features)). The parser, AST, and Intermediate Representation are [exposed as a separate `regex_syntax` crate](https://docs.rs/regex-syntax), so you don't have to write your own parser if you want to implement your own regex implementation – you can focus on the compiler / interpreter / translator itself. Another modern and widely-used implementation is [Google's RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/) which is also designed to be safe against untrusted input. (It is based on the article posted by Doc Brown.) …

Comment: … [Go's `regexp` package](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp) is more or less identical to RE2, which is not surprising since the article and RE2 were both written by Russ Cox who is also one of the Go developers. One of the most powerful regexp engines is [Onigmo](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing from the stellar answers in the comments:

### Recommendations

- The implementation of regex engines is an absolutely non trivial problem, and is best left to already defined engines.

  - simplify it as much as possible, in safer environments or with limited subsets of regular languages is the best alternative for an educational approach;
  - This because of, both the complexity inherent to designing such an engine,
    but also the complexity of making sure such a system is safe from [ReDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS).
- Even so. we have the following articles that might help with the theory of implementing such an engine, even in it's most simplistic form:

  - Ken Thompson's [article](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/363347.363387)
    mentioned in the original post;
  - An [introduction to regex engines](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html) by Russ Cox.

### Examples of Full Implementations

- Regarding full scale implementation, we also have the following github
  repositories:

  - [rust's regex](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex);
  - [Onigmo](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo);
  - [Google's re2](https://github.com/google/re2/), which relates to the
    introduction by Russ Cox.
- Rust's regex engine is notorious for it is both safe and efficient, thus
  it's extensive documentation will be linked:

  - [Regex crate](https://docs.rs/regex);
  - [Regex syntax crate](https://docs.rs/regex-syntax);
  - [Safety](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/index.html#untrusted-input);
  - The [Optional](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/#opt-out-of-unicode-support) [Unicode support](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/#unicode);
  - The [Performance features](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/index.html#performance-features).